# Can I ask questions on Algorithms,Asymptotic Analysis,Complexity Classes,Compiler Design in this forum?

Tags: discussion

This is my first question on this forum so please bear with the content of this first question.Can I post questions about the above topics on this forum?

And it will be really nice of you if you can tell me on which site of the Stack Exchange network I can post questions about 1)Computer Organization and Architecture 2)Computer Networks and 3)Operating systems. It will help me immensely and set the ball rolling for me.

StackOverflow has been very helpful to me for programming and databases.I want to avail the same help for these other subjects too.Thanks.

Comment: This is a forum for *research-level* questions on theoretical CS. For more basic questions, try cs.stackexchange, which is more suitable.

Comment: @Shaull An UG student can ask questions about all these subjects in that forum you mentioned?Including computer organization and architecture?

Comment: @Shaull I checked that forum.It has all these subjects as tags.So can you give your final suggestion.Is that forum just as good as stackoverflow?The questions there are few compared to SO.Is it good for a UG student?Will I get answers if my questions are good and genuine?

Comment: cs.se is more theoretically-oriented. So algorithms, complexity, and even networks, are very welcome. OS and computer architecture are also possible (albeit less common), and you might get good answers. You can always try, and in the worst case you won't get an answer.

Comment: This is a question for the meta-forum. Also, consider reading the faqs.

Comment: [Cs.se] is for computer *science* question, SO is for programming questions. @Shaull, no it is not just theory.

Answer (score 1):

This site is for only *research-level* questions in TCS. Typical under graduate questions are of-topic here. Please see our FAQ. The scope is explained there.